# Direct me to this question

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, pattern

[image]

What symbol should you put in the red question mark? The title can be used as a clue.

Comment: Could you include a Markdown transcription of this image (e.g., using a table) so that it is more accessible (e.g., to people using screen readers)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the title and the layout of these words...

> each word can be prepended with the cardinal direction it is relative to the question mark (maybe with some extra letters) to form a proper noun. From top left going clockwise, Northwest Territories, North(ern) Cyprus, [Northeast Corridor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northeast_Corridor), East(er) Island, [Southeast(ern) Conference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southeastern_Conference), South Park, Southwest Airlines, and West Germany.

If I had to pick a symbol to go in the middle, I'd go with...

> maybe a compass rose?
>  [image: a compass rose]